# How to show ellipsis in a list?

Tags: list

I have a list and its title column is hidden. The title columnh carries the ellipsis that opens the menu with details of the record.

How to make the ellipsis visible again while keeping the title column hidden?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Open the AllItems.aspx page for the specific list. Search for the
>    tag
>
> List item LinkToItem="TRUE" to whichever column you want the link:
>
> < ViewFields> < FieldRef Name="Attachments"/> < FieldRef
>   Name="LinkTitle"/> < FieldRef Name="linkThisColumn"
>   LinkToItem="TRUE"/> < FieldRef Name="data_x0020_column"/> < FieldRef
>   Name="Another_x0020_column"/> < /ViewFields>

See the answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53459/change-title-linked-to-item-with-edit-menu-to-different-column/53460#53460).

Comment: LinkToItem="TRUE" alone didn't work but with  LinkToItemAllowed="TRUE" ListItemMenu="TRUE" how suggested in the link works.thanks

Answer (score 2):

I realize this post is a few years old, but thought it might be handy to include another option as well. The ellipsis menu can be added to a column using CSR / JSLink as well and is a better solution than editing the AllItems.aspx or any other page directly.

The JSLInk js file might look like this:

```
(function () {

//   Initialize the variables for overrides objects
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};

//  alert("Override call worked");

    overrideCtx.Templates.OnPreRender = csrMenuAvail; 

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();

function csrMenuAvail(ctx) {
//  Specifying which column you are adding the ellipsis to based on the displayed field name. 
//  As written this will work across multiple web parts on the same page

    var numColumns = ctx.ListSchema.Field.length;
    var columnArr = ctx.ListSchema.Field;
    for (var i = 0; i < numColumns; i++)
    {
        if (columnArr[i].RealFieldName == "ColumnName")  //example 1
        {
            columnArr[i].listItemMenu = "TRUE";         
        }
    }
}
```

References:

- http://www.idubbs.com/blog/2017/js-link-add-ellipsis-to-a-column/
- Getting started with JSLink: http://www.idubbs.com/blog/2014/js-link-hello-world/
- Other JSLink references: http://www.idubbs.com/blog/js-link-and-csr/

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Gotcha. :) Updated with code sample and references. Thanks!