# WSS 3.0 - Linked to item edit menu

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-view, wss-3.0

Is the following solution applicable on WSS 3.0 with SharePoint Designer 2007?

[Change Title (linked to item with edit menu) to different column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53459/change-title-linked-to-item-with-edit-menu-to-different-column)

When I open the `AllItems.aspx` I find the `ViewFields` section looking like this:

```
&lt;ViewFields&gt;
&lt;FieldRef Name="Attachments"/&gt;
&lt;FieldRef Name="_x0395__x039a__x03a4__x0395__x03"/&gt;
&lt;FieldRef Name="_x0391__x03a1__x002e__x0020__x03"/&gt;
&lt;FieldRef Name="_x0395__x03a4__x039f__x03a3_"/&gt;
&lt;/ViewFields&gt;
```

So I tried to change it to:

```
&lt;ViewFields&gt;
&lt;FieldRef Name="Attachments"/&gt;
&lt;FieldRef Name="_x0395__x039a__x03a4__x0395__x03" LinkToItem="TRUE"/&gt;
&lt;FieldRef Name="_x0391__x03a1__x002e__x0020__x03"/&gt;
&lt;FieldRef Name="_x0395__x03a4__x039f__x03a3_"/&gt;
&lt;/ViewFields&gt;
```

Unfortunately after I save the page and preview nothing seems to change..

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? What did you do? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Nope.. Suggestions still welcome.