# Open file from document library by selecting something other than name

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

Currently to open a file you have to click on name. Is there a way to open this file by clicking on another column instead of name? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

- Open the AllItems.aspx page for the specific list.
- Search for the  tag
- List item LinkToItem="TRUE" to whichever column you want the link:

  `<ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="Attachments"/>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"/><br/>
      <FieldRef Name="linkThisColumn" LinkToItem="TRUE"/>
      <FieldRef Name="data_x0020_column"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Another_x0020_column"/>
  </ViewFields>`

[Change Title (linked to item with edit menu) to different column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53459/change-title-linked-to-item-with-edit-menu-to-different-column)

Comment: @arsalan...back in action?

Comment: This does not open the file. It oddly takes you to a location displaying the Name, Title, Doc ID and other column names.