# How do I make a column item clickable?

Tags: list, custom-list

So I'm new to SharePoint but have received help to get a list from an old 2007 TFS Site to my 2010 New Site Collection and I've been able to arrange the columns and group everything the way I want but I can't figure out how to make a column clickable so that when you click on the list item it will allow you to view the item.

So basically each row has several columns (example below). Rather than clicking the row and clicking view item I want to be able to view the item simply by clicking on App Name. I found a solution somewhere else that didn't seem to apply to me. They said that each list has a default "Title" column and if you switch up the "Title" column with the column you want to be clickable it will solve the problem. Well, I don't have a "Title" column. I'm not sure if it's because of the method I used to import the list or what but I don't have a "Title" column.

1. App Name
2. App ID
3. OPCO

This seems like something that should be fairly simple but I haven't found anything in List Settings or Site Settings. Am I simply overlooking the option? Is this possible?

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: You do have a title column, but it may no longer be called "Title" at least from your vantage point. It may be something else which you renamed it to while building the list. I do have a fix for you at work, but since I'm at home, I'll just leave this comment. You'd need to add specific coding in your aspx file while editing in Designer in order to implement, though.

Answer (score 5):

You need little SharePoint designer skills to make any column clickable.

- Open the AllItems.aspx page for the specific list.
- Search for the  tag
- List item LinkToItem="TRUE" to whichever column you want the link:

> ```
> >  <ViewFields><br/>
> >         <FieldRef Name="Attachments"/><br/>
> >         <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"/><br/>
> >         <FieldRef Name="linkThisColumn" LinkToItem="TRUE"/><br/>
> >         <FieldRef Name="data_x0020_column"/><br/>
> >         <FieldRef Name="Another_x0020_column"/><br/>
> >     </ViewFields><br/>
> ```

[Change Title (linked to item with edit menu) to different column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53459/change-title-linked-to-item-with-edit-menu-to-different-column)

http://jedmallen.com/sharepoint-2010-list-link-to-item-using-another-column-other-than-title/

Comment: Thank you for the input. However I don't have SharePoint designer access. Apparently with my company you have to have taken a class and received a certification to be allowed to download SP Designer. If this is the only method then I will pass these instructions on to my supervisor who can make the change with his access.

Answer (score 0):

There was something I was overlooking. Because I was looking for the title column I didn't notice that there was a column titled "Application Name (linked to item). I'm guessing this was the title column from the old site and it got transferred over as well.