# o365 group SharePoint list make another column clickable to open the underlying form

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, infopath, ecb-menu

Within an o365 group, I've created a test SharePoint list based on Contacts app. I've added additional columns incl. FileRefNumber.

Currently the user has to click on LastName column to open the underlying record form for editing or viewing. Instead of Lastname, I'd like to use FileRefNumber as the clickable column.

I'm using Infopath2013 to modify & publish changes to the form eg. re-arrange fields in the sequence I require or cosmetic changes to rename labels and so on. But can't see any option in InfoPath to change from the default clickable column.

other articles suggest using SPD to:

- Open the AllItems.aspx page for the specific list.
- Search for the tag
- List item LinkToItem="TRUE" to whichever column you want the link:
- LinkToItem="TRUE"

This is not working for me. can't see fields nor LinkToItem.

Refs: these are for SP10

- [How do I make a column item clickable?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110739/how-do-i-make-a-column-item-clickable)
- https://teylyn.com/2012/05/01/link-to-edit-item-ecb-on-another-column-than-title-no-code/

Comment: Hi @JayRatansi, welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge :) Thank you for your contribution :)