# LinkToItem not linking to document

Tags: column

I have tried `linkToItem="TRUE"` but it doesn't work on my SP2013 version but `LinkToItem="TRUE"` does.

Only one issue, the **LinkToItem** doesn't open the file, it just opens the edit/item screen.

How do I link a column to open the actual document with the selected method in SharePoint(Open in client application/browser). Is there a LinkToFile or something similar I could use?

Comment: check this one http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/c3eb964c-778c-417c-806f-743d940044f7/how-to-modify-list-column-to-link-to-document-and-allow-edit

Comment: More accurate and concise answer on SE: [Change Title (linked to item with edit menu) to different column](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53459/change-title-linked-to-item-with-edit-menu-to-different-column?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 3):

This is how you get it to work

`< ViewFields>
    < FieldRef Name=”Attachments”/>
    < FieldRef Name=”LinkTitle”/>
    < FieldRef Name=”linkThisColumn” ListItemMenu="TRUE" linkToItem="TRUE"/>
    < FieldRef Name=”data_x0020_column”/>
    < FieldRef Name=”Another_x0020_column”/>
    < /ViewFields>`