# SharePoint 2013 make Title clickable to item like the Name field

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a 2013 document library. The Name field is clickable to the item. I want a Title field that is clickable to that item just like the Name field in the document library. I have followed the steps as on [Change Title (linked to item with edit menu) to different column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53459/change-title-linked-to-item-with-edit-menu-to-different-column). But it is not working.

Comment: Can you post the xml you tried with

Comment: Hope you had followed the "if you're trying this for SharePoint 2013, change "LinkToItem" to "linkToItem"" in the link you specifed.

Comment: @ Mp Arvind yes I have tried linkToItem but to no avail.

Comment: @ Amal Hashim I haven't used any xml. I just opened the list in SPD 2013 and specified    <Query/>
   <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="Title" linkToItem="TRUE"/>
    <FieldRef Name="DocIcon"/>
    <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"/>
    <FieldRef Name="Modified"/>
    <FieldRef Name="Editor"/>
   </ViewFields>
   <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
   <Aggregations Value="Off"/>
   <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
   <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
   <Toolbar Type="Standard"/>

Comment: Truly do not get why this is even an issue. If they want us to use CamelCase or underscores or something in the name to get the URL to not have %20, then they need to allow the Title to be linked so the end users can find the files they want! I do not have access to SharePoint Designer (locked out by IT) and this is a huge issue in both 2010 and 2013 and prevents user adoption! Any suggestions without using SPD?