# Is it possible to create a Managed Metadata column that acts as a link to the item?

Tags: managed-metadata, column

I have a managed metadata term set that is basically acting as a foreign key to link various sets of data together. IE something like one list has widgets, which has a column for like, the material it is made of, and the name of the material is a term set, and then there is a list which has each material and additional columns with details about that material.

So I have a list which has a metadata column that is both Unique and Required, and is effectively the "Title" of that item. Is there any way to have that column function like the Title with link does, where it links to the item and/or has that drop down menu for editing/etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you edit a list view with SharePoint designer, you can designate any column to have the edit menu drop-down. See here: [Change Title (linked to item with edit menu) to different column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53459/change-title-linked-to-item-with-edit-menu-to-different-column)